# Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices System.FormatException: RestrictAssociationToId

Tags: 2013, deployment, visual-studio-2012, workflow-manager

When trying to run provider-hosted add-in containing workflow in Visual Studio output window I get this error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices System.FormatException:
>   RestrictAssociationToId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had not included target list and history list in the feature.

More details on http://slavensemper.blogspot.hr/2015/12/running-project-with-workflow-in.html.